# Vue3 top-level await Eslint fails

Tags: async-await, eslint, vuejs3, async-components, top-level-await

Following the official documentation: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#top-level-await

I'm trying to create an async component like that:

```
<template>
  <p>Async data: {{asyncData}}</p>
</template>

<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'
const asyncData = ref(null)
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
await sleep(2000);
asyncData.value = 'abcd1234'
</script>
```

The component works fine.
The problem is: Eslint detects that error:

`Parsing error: Cannot use keyword 'await' outside an async function`

How can I deal with that?

In fact it's Vue who is forcing me to write an invalid code...

Answer (score 1):

I see it can be solved updating Eslint config:

`.eslintrc.cjs`

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: "module",
    ecmaVersion: 2022,
  },
  ...
};
```

But shouldn't be as default?

Comment: Hello @marc-pont.  Could you please elaborate for people that are new to Vue.js where exactly this configuration is or goes?  Is it a new file that is created?  Is there a need for a plug in?  Etc.  Details for newbies.

Answer (score 0):

**Parsing error with Top Level await:**

**Using ESLint <= v7.x**

> The parser espree that comes with ESLint v7.x doesn't understand the syntax of ES2022, so it can't parse the Top Level await either.
> However, espree >= v8 can understand the syntax of ES2022 and parse the Top Level await.
> You install espree >= v8 and specify "espree" and ES2022 in your configuration, the parser will be able to parse it.

```
module.exports = {
  parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'espree',
    ecmaVersion: 2022,
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
}
```

**Using ESLint >= v8.x**

> You need to specify 2022 or "latest" for parserOptions.ecmaVersion.

```
module.exports = {
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
}
```